# How to Load Images into a Win32 App without changing Linker/Compiler Settings

Tags: c++, image, winapi, gdi

I need to display Images inside of a Win32 Frame. I can currently only load Bitmaps and Icons using the LoadImage function but i also need to open jpg and png images.

I cant use Gdi+ because I'm required to use CodeBlocks with GCC and must not change any compiler/linker settings.

Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: That's an odd requirement. What's the specific reason you cannot change the set of required import libraries? While you can use the Windows Imaging Component, not using import libraries is just going to make your life needlessly complicated.

Comment: Can you load `gdiplus.dll` via `LoadLibrary`?

Comment: @pau GDI+ is pretty much MSVC-only. It uses the WIC internally, so you can just use the WIC directly.

Comment: @IInspectable So gcc can't load Windows DLLs?  How does it get anything done?

Comment: @pau Loading the DLL isn't the issue. The problem is the C++ wrappers that most likely will not compile with GCC.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh, OK.  That would make sense.